# __call__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'

Tags: python, django

```py
class CreateProject(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, editable_object=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateProject, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        use_required_attribute = True
        self.fields['tasks'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            widget=forms.SelectMultiple(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }
            ),
            queryset=Task.objects.filter(company=user.company),
            required=True,
            initial=editable_object.tasks if editable_object else None,
            label='Tasks'
        )
```

When I try to give editable_object parameter (object of Project model) it can't make initial value for tasks field, when I remove initial value for this field it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an answer.
As ManyToManyField values aren't QuerySet object, we have to filter it like we do it with Model.objects

```
initial=editable_object.tasks.all() if editable_object else None
# code
```

Answer (score 1):

For future visitors, I had the error showing when I was -for example- doing the following:

```
enrollments = user.enrollments().all()
```

After changing the filtering to this way it was correct:

```
enrollments = user.enrollments.all()
```

A very nice example helped me overcome this error here [here](https://www.revsys.com/tidbits/tips-using-djangos-manytomanyfield/)!.